# Change start point of LeveyPopListView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using [LeveyPopListView](https://github.com/levey/LeveyPopListView) and I want to change the start point of LeveyPopListView not the _tableView inside. I want to make the start point of LeveyPopLostView on the start of the tableview (7-11 cell). I tried changing the POPLISTVIEW_SCREENINSET, but it just moves the tableview inside the alert view.

Please help. 
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the values of: POPLISTVIEW_SCREENINSET, POPLISTVIEW_HEADER_HEIGHT. I changed the values to 0 and 10 respectively to get below presentation. Change the frame settings in the initWithTitle method of "LeveyPopListView".

Comment: I am unable to add image due to less reputation.

Comment: I recommend to add a delegate to set the frame of the overlay view. This way it will be flexible. Could you please provide details on the use case? The reason I am requesting for information is, this is an overlay view representation and adjusting it to the table view letf-top  corner may not add much of value.

Comment: i need leveypoplistview to be full screen, so that the user cannot scroll on the tableview behind it, because it causes multiple display of the leveypoplistview.